# Storing a yes or no value in a database with a check box in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am making a modal in Laravel and I cannot seem to wrap my head around the check boxes. I want to have a box called updated where when checked, it is 1 and if unchecked it is 0, as this is a not null field in my db, it needs to have this value.

here is my code below:

```
   <div>
        <input name="updated" type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck1" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="btncheck1">Updated</label>
      </div>
```

I am not so sure what should go in my controller as this is my first time working in Laravel for checkboxes.

Comment: you can do truthy value operation like `db::update('updated', !! $request['updated']);`

Comment: where would that go

Comment: in your controller you should use `function update(Request $request)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with:

View (input):

```
<input name="updated" value="checked" type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck1" autocomplete="off">
```

Controller:

```
function update(Request $request, $id){
    DB::table('book')->where('id',$id)->update([
        'is_checked' => $request->updated == "checked" ? 1 : 0
    ]);
}
```